# Center div within another div and prevent it from going out

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I developed a div, inside that div I intend to put an image and then a set of two divs.

Is there a way to center the two divs below and prevent them from going outside the main div when the screen is reduced?

Can someone help me?

[**DEMO - Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-webbmu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**code**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="drop">
        <div class="abc">
            <img src="https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/2x3/2.jpg">
            <div class="boxImage" style="display:flex">
                <div class="boxImage1">
                </div>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I center the two divs?

[image]

How can I prevent them from leaving the main div?

[image: Images]

Comment: Are you trying to center the divs on top of the image or below it?

Comment: @JamesShaver I intend to center the divs one that are just below the image, they are signaled with green in the images.
Many thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this answers your question, but here's my take at it. I had to make some changes to your css because the boxImage classes were throwing it off a bit.  I set the background color on those divs so that you can see where they're laying in the screen.

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center p-2"><img src="https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/2x3/2.jpg"></div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 boxImage1">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 boxImage">Flex item 2</div>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
    .drop {
    height: 670px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eff0f2;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;

}

.abc {
    height: 100%;
  background-image: ('https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/2x3/2.jpg');
  }



.abc .boxImage {
    position: absolute;
    right: 27px;
    bottom: 40px;
}

.abc .boxImage1 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 373px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.boxImage {
    background-color: red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 60%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.boxImage1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 18px;
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

Comment: That's almost what I intend! The problem with this resolution is that it does not contain the class drop and I intend to use it. Thank you so much for trying to help me!

Comment: Glad to help! To be honest, I couldn't tell what you were trying to do with the drop class, and it seemed to be in the way so I left it out :)